# Firebase, Flutter: Check if User Signed In With Apple

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

Did some searching and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to determine if a user signed in with Apple (or really any other provider) in Firebase with Flutter? See the image below. Firebase knows it was an Apple sign in, but not sure how to check the provider to see if was Apple or another method.

[image]

Comment: You can loop over the `providerData` for the user, and then check the provider IDs in there: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/providerData.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can access FirebaseUser property called providerData which type is List. UserInfo has a providerId which is for ex. google.com, facebook.com, apple.com, password (email) or phone.

You can find those values looking up the code.

```
print(user.providerData[0].providerId) // -> fe. google.com
```